# PostgreSQL - Actualizar tabla con valores acumulados (suma de fechas anteriores) de otra tabla

Tags: postgresql, update, sum

quiero actualizar una tabla con la sumatoria de una segunda tabla

La tabla "historic_mov" almacena los movimientos almacenados con la fecha inicial y la fecha de inicio de operación

| id_suc | fecha_operacion | mov_inicial | mov_final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-02-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2020-02-02 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2020-02-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2020-02-02 | 0 | 0 |

"view_mov_diario" es una tabla que almacena los movimientos al día, la diferencia con "historic_mov" es que esta no almacena los movimientos de manera acumulada

| id_suc | fecha_operacion | movimiento |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-29 | 500 |
| 1 | 2020-02-01 | 100 |
| 1 | 2020-02-02 | 200 |
| 2 | 2020-01-29 | 750 |
| 2 | 2020-02-01 | 100 |
| 2 | 2020-02-02 | 250 |

Quiero realizar un update para que los movimientos se puedan acumular en la tabla histórica y se vea de la siguiente manera:

| id_suc | fecha_operacion | mov_inicial | mov_final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-02-01 | 500 | 600 |
| 1 | 2020-02-02 | 600 | 800 |
| 2 | 2020-02-01 | 750 | 850 |
| 2 | 2020-02-02 | 850 | 1100 |

El campo mov_inicial almacena la suma de movimientos de "view_mov" menores la fecha_operacion.
El campo mov_final almacena la suma de movimientos de "view_mov" hasta la fecha_operacion.
En los dos casos la única relación que tienen es el id_suc

Intente con este script, pero el proceso solo lo ejecuta y no lo concluye:

```
UPDATE historic_mov
    SET 
        mov_inicial= (select sum(view_mov_diario.movimiento) 
            from public.view_mov_diario where 
            view_mov_diario.fecha_operacion > '2020-11-01' and view_mov_diario.fecha_operacion < historic_mov.fecha_operacion 
            and view_mov_diario.id_suc = historic_mov.id_suc),
        mov_final= (select sum(view_mov_diario.movimiento) 
            from public.view_mov_diario where 
            view_mov_diario.fecha_operacion between '2020-11-01' and historic_mov.fecha_operacion 
            and view_mov_diario.id_suc = historic_mov.id_suc);
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0):

Con está query podés calcular los valores de mov_inicial y mov_final para cada id_suc y fecha_operacion de la tabla historic_mov.

```
SELECT aux1.d_suc, aux1.fecha_operacion, aux1.sumaAntesFecha, aux2.sumaHastaFecha

FROM (
    SELECT h.d_suc, h.fecha_operacion, SUM(d1.movimiento) AS sumaAntesFecha
    FROM historic_mov h
    INNER JOIN view_mov_diario d1 ON d1.d_suc = h.d_suc AND d1.fecha_operacion < h.fecha_operacion
    GROUP BY h.d_suc, h.fecha_operacion
) AS aux1

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT h.d_suc, h.fecha_operacion, SUM(d2.movimiento) AS sumaHastaFecha
    FROM historic_mov h
    INNER JOIN view_mov_diario d2 ON d2.d_suc = h.d_suc AND d2.fecha_operacion <= h.fecha_operacion
    GROUP BY h.d_suc, h.fecha_operacion
) AS aux2 ON aux1.d_suc = aux2.d_suc AND aux1.fecha_operacion = aux2.fecha_operacion

ORDER BY aux1.d_suc, aux1.fecha_operacion;
```

Con esta query puedes hacer el update:

```
UPDATE historic_mov h
    SET mov_inicial = sumaAntesFecha,
    mov_final = sumaHastaFecha

FROM (
    SELECT h.d_suc, h.fecha_operacion, SUM(d1.movimiento) AS sumaAntesFecha
    FROM historic_mov h
    INNER JOIN view_mov_diario d1 ON d1.d_suc = h.d_suc AND d1.fecha_operacion < h.fecha_operacion
    GROUP BY h.d_suc, h.fecha_operacion
) AS aux1

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT h.d_suc, h.fecha_operacion, SUM(d2.movimiento) AS sumaHastaFecha
    FROM historic_mov h
    INNER JOIN view_mov_diario d2 ON d2.d_suc = h.d_suc AND d2.fecha_operacion <= h.fecha_operacion
    GROUP BY h.d_suc, h.fecha_operacion
) AS aux2 ON aux1.d_suc = aux2.d_suc AND aux1.fecha_operacion = aux2.fecha_operacion

WHERE h.d_suc = aux1.d_suc AND h.fecha_operacion = aux1.fecha_operacion;
```